# Pluggable reporting tools in C# WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, reporting-services, reporting

My application needs the ability to create and produce reports and it seems that the 2 major options are SSRS or Crystal Reports with a whole host of other options like Infragistics, Active Reports and so on.

As the application will be used in a variety of different corporate environments there will be different prefrences for which is their reporting tool. So for example 1 customer might be a SSRS user and another might think that Crystal is the best thing ever.

This means that it is important not to tie my application to one particular reporting tool but have the ability to plug in the relevant one out of a list of many.

Has anyone done something similar?
At the general level, how would you go about implementing this and what problems should I look out for?

Thanks in advance for any help

Alex

Comment: do you need pluggable reporting at runtime or make choice before building your application according to the destination environment ?

Comment: I think in practical terms it is going to be a lot easier to make the choice before deploying to the destination environment. I think that there will be too much overhead otherwise.

Comment: PRISM has given me the oppertunity to make two modules each one has it's own reporting engin but the way the application interacts with them is practically the same.

Comment: I think that the PRISM route has some merit as my current application is using a lot of the PRISM framework. Can I ask how do you interact with the reporting modules from the main application? Thanks

Comment: For my case I'm using EventAggregator so i can call functions from any module. the tip is to load only the desired reporting module.

Comment: Final question on this, did you manage to make one Event (for the EventAggregator) that covered both reporting tools or did you end up making specific events per reporting - that is if I decided to support N reporting tools would I need to create N events?

Comment: Absolutely not all modules would subscribe to same calls from the app but the only loaded would react and excute.

Comment: You don't raise events for user interactions, you use Commands.  Also, Im assuming you wish to show the report in a Modal context, in which case events are irrelevant.  If you would like help on the selection of the report itself, please post the code you are using to query the user

Comment: I always use commands for user interactions.I do use EventAggregator for communication betwen modules

Answer (score 1):

The problem you will likely have is that all these systems use their own datasource objects and rendering engines, you will need to implement each system separately with its own proprietary viewer control.  You could probably style all the viewers to look the same but they will like not all have the same functions.

If you are using business objects as your datasource, I highly recommend sending your data to a database first, as you will find much less overhead on each reporting solution if you are pulling your data directly from a  DB.

Each report viewer (the ones from each different reporting solution) will allow you to strip off everything from the viewer except the main Report View pane.  You can then implement your own buttons like "Print, export to PDF, XLS, Zoom, Page Back, Page Forward.  There are more.  You can then wire your buttons to functions on the the report viewer control i.e. Viewer.Zoom(100).  You will likely be wasting a lot of time on this though as it is a lot of effort to recode buttons that are already there and functional, just so that they look the same.

Comment: My intention was to have the data pulled directly from the DB - however that still leaves the problem as you say that each vendor has different implementations - I think it is a question of how to hide this detail?

Comment: Define 'hide', you said the user will know whether they want to use Crystal or SSRS, so they will choose which one they want and you will bring up a window that will show either the Crystal or the SSRS report viewer

Comment: Thinking about that again, I guess 'hide' means I need to define an interface that is the same from my application but is implemented using the various report controls in the reporting modules.

Comment: Added an edit, though I highly recommend re-considering just using the out-of-the-box reportviewers, they have different icons but essentially all provide the same features.